# Sphinx is running under Anaconda but my django project is under Python 3.5.2

Tags: anaconda, python-sphinx

I'm triyng to documentate my django project with Sphinx but I have some trouble.

When I run `make html` command I'm getting this error:

```
/home/santoryu/richiestaTesi/docs/models/models.rst:3: WARNING: autodoc: 
failed to import module u'myapp.models'; the following exception was 
raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/santoryu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-
1.5.6-py2.7.egg/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 560, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/santoryu/richiestaTesi/myapp/models.py", line 8
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file 
/home/santoryu/richiestaTesi/myapp/models.py on line 8, but no encoding 
declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

It's clear that the error happens because in Anaconda Non-ASCII characters are not supported natively but in Python 3.5.2 they are. So I'm guessing how to force Sphinx executed by Python 3.5.2?

Comment: Is the project being documented python 3 specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that you installed Sphinx into a Python 2.7 virtual environment.

```
  File "/home/santoryu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Sphinx-
1.5.6-py2.7.egg/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 560, in import_object
__import__(self.modname)
```

It's also possible that you installed Anaconda for Python 2.7 instead of 3.6.

Make sure that you download and install Anaconda for Python 3.6 and that you [use Anaconda to create a virtual environment using Python 3.6](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) for installing Sphinx.